# Query returning an ascending group number

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query like below that has groups (COL1) and that group's values (COL2).

```
select col1,
       col2
  from (select 'A' col1, 1 col2 from dual union all
        select 'A' col1, 2 col2 from dual union all
        select 'B' col1, 1 col2 from dual union all
        select 'B' col1, 2 col2 from dual union all
        select 'C' col1, 1 col2 from dual union all
        select 'C' col1, 2 col2 from dual
       )
order by col1,
         col2;
```

The output of this query looks like:

```
COL1 COL2
---- ----
A    1
A    2
B    1
B    2
C    1
C    2
```

What I need is a query that will return an ordered number increasing for each different group (COL1).  It seems like there would be a simple way to accomplish this (maybe with analytics) but for some reason it is escaping me.

```
GRPNUM COL1 COL2
------ ---- ----
1      A    1
1      A    2
2      B    1
2      B    2
3      C    1
3      C    2
```

I am running Oracle 10gR2.

Comment: Not knowing what you are using this for, I could be missing something, but this really seems like it would be better handled by the program processing the data rather than in the query itself.

Comment: It a query for a data conversion generating data for a parent/child set of tables.  GRPNUM becoming the parent table unique ID, correlating with the child record data (COL1, COL2).  I'm trying to get everything generated in this one query to simplify my inserts, but I have a solution where I can separate it out.  I'm just trying to avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work:

```
SQL> WITH qry AS (
  2       select 'A' col1, 1 col2 from dual union all
  3       select 'A' col1, 2 col2 from dual union all
  4       select 'B' col1, 1 col2 from dual union all
  5       select 'B' col1, 2 col2 from dual union all
  6       select 'C' col1, 1 col2 from dual union all
  7       select 'C' col1, 2 col2 from dual
  8  )
  9  SELECT dense_rank() over (ORDER BY col1) grpnum,
 10         col1,
 11         col2
 12    FROM qry
 13   ORDER BY col1, col2;

    GRPNUM COL1       COL2
---------- ---- ----------
         1 A             1
         1 A             2
         2 B             1
         2 B             2
         3 C             1
         3 C             2
```

Comment: Perfect, I tried `dense_rank` but kept getting caught up trying to partition my data.  This works swimmingly.

Answer (score 1):

try DENSE_RANK.

```
select DENSE_RANK() OVER(partition by col2 order by col1, col2) as GRPNUM, 
       COL1, COL2
from ....
```

For the given data this works but i don't know if it'll work for the real dataset.

Comment: That returns an ordered ascending value for each col1 (1, A, 1), (2, A, 2), (1, B, 1), (1, B, 2) etc.  I was trying out row_number( ) and running into the same thing.

Comment: try partitioning by col2 instead of col1

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Oracle handy, so there may be some dialect issues, but how about something like this: Create a temporary table from "distinct col1", assign sequence numbers to it, and then join against this. Something like:

```
create sequence groupnumber;

create temp_group (grpnum int, col1 varchar(20), col2 varchar(20));

insert into temp_group
select next_val('groupnumber'), col1
from
(select distinct col1 from incoming
order by col1);

select grpnum, col1, col2
from incoming
join temp_group using (col1)
order by col1, col2;
```

(You could probably use the oracle rownumber instead of the sequence.)